# php/apache performance

Tags: php, performance, apache

Which one is better and why? Can someone please explain it to me? Thanks a lot.

```
//Example 1
if($var == 1)
{
    echo "text text text..."; //Note: large text like 1MB 
}
```

or

```
//Example 2
if($var == 1)
{
    echo file_get_contents("path/to/file"); //content of this file same as echo text above
}
```

Comment: The question makes no sense without detailed context. The most efficient would be to serve the file directly by apache. And, yes, you can compare the performance **yourself** using apache `ab` tool

Comment: Step 2. It decouples your data from your code.

Comment: @Jitamaro: Don't be so categorical!

Comment: @zerkms: I'm hierarchical, it's more like a command. Nothing to do with a box.

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving a whole megabyte of static content, definitely let Apache do it -- it can use the `sendfile(2)` system call to avoid double-copies, doesn't force PHP to reparse a giant string over and over and over again, and best yet, makes your PHP files tolerable to edit. (Sure, a megabyte isn't *that* big these days, but separating content from presentation is always a worthwhile goal.)

Answer (score 0):

> php/apache performance

What, in this question, is specific to apache?

> Which one is better

In what regard? The first option is a very messy construct, and will perform poorly - but there are better ways to incorporate bulk content within the script without mapping it into PHP variable space, e.g.

```
if($var != 1)
{
   // do something else
   exit;
}
?>
text text text... <!-- Note: large text like 1MB -->
```

In terms of processing load, then minimising the amount of data parsed by PHP (i.e. the entire file) will help as will reducing the amount of data processed by PHP (i.e. the stuff within <?php ... ?> )

But another important question is how you manage the content - embedding large amounts of data within a PHP is not the right solution - editing code is a different task/responsibility from editing HTML content.

..and if you're just talking about performance, why don't you measure it yourself?